# Development workflow for server and client using Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm developing a server and its client simultaneously and I'm designing them in Docker containers.  I'm using Docker Compose to link them up and it works just fine for production but I can't figure out how to make it work with a development workflow in which I've got a shell running for each one.

My `docker-compose-devel.yml`:

```
server:
  image: node:0.10

client:
  image: node:0.10
  links:
    - server
```

I can do `docker-compose up client` or even `docker-compose run client` but what I want is a shell running for both server and client so I can make rapid changes to both as I develop iteratively.

I want to be able to do `docker-compose run server bash` in one window and `docker-compose run --no-deps client bash` in another window.  The problem with this is that no address for the server is added to `/etc/hosts` on the client because I'm using `docker-compose run` instead of `up`.

The only solution I can figure out is to use `docker run` and give up on Docker Compose for development.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution I came up with that's hackish; please let me know if you can do better.

`docker-compose-devel.yml`:

```
server:
  image: node:0.10
  command: sleep infinity

client:
  image: node:0.10
  links:
    - server
```

In window 1:

```
docker-compose --file docker-compose-dev.yml up -d server
docker exec --interactive --tty $(docker-compose --file docker-compose-dev.yml ps -q server) bash
```

In window 2:

```
docker-compose --file docker-compose-dev.yml run client bash
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your main problem is about restarting the application when there are changes in the code.

Personnaly, I launch my applications in development containers using forever.

```
forever -w -o log/out.log -e log/err.log app.js
```

The `w` option restarts the server when there is a change in the code.

I use a `.foreverignore` file to exclude the changes on some files:

```
**/.tmp/**
**/views/**
**/assets/**
**/log/**
```

If needed, I can also launch a shell in a running container:

```
docker exec -it my-container-name bash
```

This way, your two applications could restart independently without the need to launch the commands yourself. And you have the possibility to open a shell to do whatever you want.

---

**Edit:** New proposition considering that you need two interactive shells and not simply the possibility to relaunch the apps on code changes.

Having two distinct applications, you could have a `docker-compose` configuration for each one.

The `docker-compose.yml` from the "server" app could contain this kind of information (I added different kind of configurations for the example):

```
server:
  image: node:0.10
  links:
    - db
  ports:
   - "8080:80"
  volumes:
   - ./src:/src
db:
  image: postgres
  environment:
   POSTGRES_USER: dev
   POSTGRES_PASSWORD: dev
```

The `docker-compose.yml` from the "client" app could use [`external_links`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#external-links) to be able to connect to the server.

```
client:
  image: node:0.10
  external_links:
   - project_server_1:server  # Use "docker ps" to know the name of the server's container
  ports:
   - "80:80"
  volumes:
   - ./src:/src
```

Then, use `docker-compose run --service-ports service-name bash` to launch each configuration with an interactive shell.

Alternatively, the [`extra-hosts`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#extra-hosts) key may also do the trick by calling the server app threw a port exposed on the host machine.

With this solution, each docker-compose.yml file could be commited in the repository of the related app.

Comment: Thank you.  I like the suggestion of using Forever.  I don't like the idea of running a shell independently because I want to watch stdout of my server.

Comment: Using `docker compose up` (without the -d option),  you will be able to watch stdout. I  mentionned `docker exec`,  but it is optional and only if you want do execute some command in the container for whatever reason.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in my question, but I want an interactive shell for both server and client.

Comment: Could you consider using a docker-compose.yml file for the server and another one for the client?

Comment: I don't understand how that would help.  Would you like to update your answer with an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

First thing to mention, for **development environment** you want to utilize **volumes** from docker-compose to **mount your app to the container** when it's started (**at the runtime**). Sorry if you're already doing it and I mention this, but it's not clear from your definition of `docker-compose.yml`

To answer your specific question - start your containers normally, then when doing `docker-compose ps`, you'll see a name of your container. For example 'web_server' and 'web_client' (where **web** is the directory of your docker-compose.yml file or name of the project).

When you got name of the container you want to connect to, you can run this command to run bash exactly in the container that's running your server:

`docker exec -it web_server bash`.

If you want to learn more about setting up development environment for reasonably complex app, checkout [this article on development with docker-compose](http://howtocookmicroservices.com/docker-compose/)

Comment: Thanks; I don't want to run a shell independently because I want to watch stdout from my server.