# Docker Compose keep container running

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to start a service with docker-compose and keep the container running so I can get its IP-address via 'docker inspect'. However, the container always exits right after starting up.

I tried to add "command: ["sleep", "60"]" and other things to the docker-compose.yml but whenever I add the line with "command:..." I cant call "docker-compose up" as I will get the message "Cannot start container ..... System error: invalid character 'k' looking for beginning of value"

I also tried adding "CMD sleep 60" and whatnot to the Dockerfile itself but these commands do not seem to be executed.

Is there an easy way to keep the container alive or to fix one of my problems?

EDIT:
Here is the Compose file I want to run:

```
version: '2'
services:
  my-test:
    image: ubuntu
    command: bash -c "while true; do echo hello; sleep 2; done"
```

It's working fine If I start this with docker-compose under OS X, but if I try the same under Ubuntu 16.04 it gives me above error message.

If I try the approach with the Dockerfile, the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
CMD ["sleep", "60"]
```

Which does not seem to do anything

EDIT 2:
I have to correct myself, turned out it was the same problem with the Dockerfile and the docker-compose.yml:
Each time I add either "CMD ..." to the Dockerfile OR add "command ..." to the compose file, I get above error with the invalid character. If I remove both commands, it works flawlessly.

Comment: Please include the docker-compose.yml, Dockerfile, and any scripts you're trying to debug.

Comment: A related discussion, for those interested: [Development workflow for server and client using Docker Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31372886/320399)

Answer (score 281, accepted):

To keep a container running when you start it with `docker-compose`, use the following command

`command: tail -F anything`

In the above command the last part `anything` should be included literally, and the assumption is that such a file is not present in the container, but with the `-F` option (capital `-F` not to be confused with `-f` which in contrast will terminate immediateley if the file is not found) the `tail` command will wait forever for the file `anything` to appear. A forever waiting process is basically what we need.

So your docker-compose.yml becomes

```
version: '2'
services:
  my-test:
    image: ubuntu
    command: tail -F anything
```

and you can run a shell to get into the container using the following command

`docker exec -i -t composename_my-test_1 bash`

where `composename` is the name that `docker-compose` prepends to your containers.

Comment: How do you stop the container when you are done with it? Is there a Ctrl+C, Ctrl+Z type of command? Right now I have to close the terminal to quit.

Comment: If you are inside of the container, you can type `exit` to get back to your host machine. If you are on your host, then you can stop the container using Docker (`docker stop composename_my-test_1`) or Docker Compose (`docker-compose stop`).

Comment: This did not work for me, when I do `docker ps -a` the container status shows `Restarting (0) 5 seconds ago` and when I try `docker exec -it data-quality-test-db-sqlite sh` it says `Error response from daemon: Container [...] is restarting, wait until the container is running`

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland If you are willing to ask a new SO question and share some more details, then I'd be more than happy to take a look. My guess is that your error has something to do with the internals of one of your containers, as opposed to an issue with Docker or your host operating system.

Comment: @mac10688 if there is no prompt in your attached container session then try ctrl-d to detach

Comment: `/dev/null` would be better in place for `anything` for tail command ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48732671/248616

Comment: As an alternative to `/dev/null`, you could replace `anything` with a log file that gives you insight into what the container is doing. While the literal `anything` will work, what I really meant is that `tail -F` for some file or stream is a good way to start a foreground process and keep a container running.

Comment: You can also add the docker-compose line: `restart: unless-stopped` to help it know you want to distinguish between intentional `stop` and the command stopping.

Comment: I'm used to doing this using the `entrypoint` entry, but now I need to replace a single command with an entrypoint file and even though I still have `tail -f /dev/null` at the end of my `entrypoint.sh` file, the container still exits right away. Is there any way I can run the file and keep the container up?

Comment: i am just adding to the discussion, trying to understand the best pratice, would tmux or screen be used for this?

Answer (score 255):

You can use `tty` configuration option.

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    image: node:8
    tty: true           # <-- This option
```

*Note: If you use Dockerfile for image and `CMD` in Dockerfile, this option won't work; however, you can use the `entrypoint` option in the compose file which clears the `CMD` from the Dockerfile.*

Comment: This works, and seems less hacky than `tail -f /dev/null`. With this, I'm able to run a containerized dev environment with a postgres database attached via `docker-compose up` and run a shell through another terminal using `docker exec`.

Comment: While currently NOT well documented. This is an official options that will achieve the same effect as `tail -f /dev/null` or `tail -f anything`,  see here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Comment: @ABMRuman & Psiloc, It works only when you don't use "command" in the docker-compose.yml file. When using "command"  you need another hack - hence the tail -F hack is perfectly suited here.

Comment: This must be the best answer if you use entrypoint in dockerfile.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, the container still dies. It works if I add `tail -F /dev/null` in my entrypoint bash script, but it's weird to rely on that bash script being alive when all I want is to run some initial commands when the container is started.

Comment: Works for me, very clean.

Answer (score 88):

Based on [the comment of @aanand on GitHub Aug 26, 2015](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1926#issuecomment-135068628), one could use `tail -f /dev/null` in docker-compose to keep the container running.

**docker-compose.yml example**

```
version: '3'
services:
  some-app:
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

**Why this command?**

The only reason for choosing this option was that it received a lot of thumbs up on GitHub, but the highest voted answer does not mean that it is the best answer. The second reason was a pragmatic one as issues had to be solved as soon as possible due to deadlines.

Comment: why exactly this command? What makes it better than others?
In my case just starting a bash did the trick as well...

Comment: @N4ppeL Good question. The only reason I choose this option was that it received a lot of thumbs up on github, but the highest voted answer does not mean that it is the best answer. The second reason was a pragmatic one as I had to solve the issue as soon as possible due to deadlines.

Comment: this overrides origin entrypoint, didnt execute origin entrypoint

Answer (score 27):

- Create a file called `docker-compose.yml`
- Add the following to the file

```
version: "3"

services:
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    tty: true
```

- Staying in the same directory, run `docker-compose up -d` from the terminal
- Run `docker ps` to get the container id or name
- You can run `docker inspect $container_id`
- You can enter the container and get a bash shell running `docker-compose exec ubuntu /bin/bash` or `docker-compose exec ubuntu /bin/sh`
- When done, make sure you are outside the container and run `docker-compose down`

Here's a small bash script (`my-docker-shell.sh`) to create the docker compose file, run the container, login to the container and then finally cleanup the docker container and the docker compose file when you log out.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cat << 'EOF' > ./docker-compose.yml
---

version: "3"

services:
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    command: /bin/bash
    # tty: true

...
EOF

printf "Now entering the container...\n"
docker-compose run ubuntu bash
docker-compose down

rm -v ./docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: While this wasn't an actual answer to the question, I found it extremely valuable!

I went further to use global bashrc functions for this approach: https://gist.github.com/loopmode/4d59a4e9a0a2ffacaec2dd14db4ae8bd

Comment: It would however overwrite any existing `docker-compose.yml` file in the current directory; bit dangerous.

Answer (score 20):

I'm late to the party, but you can simply use: `stdin_open: true`

```
version: '2'
services:
  my-test:
    image: ubuntu
    stdin_open: true
```

Answer (score 15):

Some people here write about overwriting the `entrypoint` so that the `command` can also have its effect. But no one gives an example. I then:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:

    etfwebapp:
        # For messed up volumes and `sudo docker cp`:
        command: "-f /dev/null"
        entrypoint: /usr/bin/tail
        tty: true

# ...
```

I am not sure if `tty` is needed at this point. Is it better to do it twice? In my case it did no harm and worked perfectly. Without `entrypoint` it didn't work for me because then `command` had no effect. So I guess for this solution `tty` is optional.

To understand which command is executed at start-up, simply read the `entrypoint` before the `command` (concat with space): `/usr/bin/tail -f /dev/null`.

Answer (score 12):

In the Dockerfile you can use the command:

```
{CMD sleep infinity}
```

Answer (score 11):

Blocking command is all you need.

I have been struggling with this problem for half a day.
. There are many answers below, but not clear enough. And nobody said why.

In short, there are two methods, but it can also be said that there is only one, running a `Blocking processes` in background.

---

This first one is using `COMMAND`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  some-app:
    command: ["some block command"]
```

put some block command like  `sleep infinity`, `tail -f /dev/null`, `watch anything`, `while true` ...

Here I recommend `sleep infinity`.

---

The second is enable `tty=true`, then open a shell in command like `/bin/bash`.

```
services:
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    tty: true
    command: "/bin/bash"
```

Since the tty is enabled, bash will keep running background, you can put some other block commands before it if you want.

**Be careful**, you must excute shell command at the end, like

```
command: /bin/bash -c "/root/.init-service && /bin/bash"
```

---

As you can see, all you need is blocking command.

Answer (score 5):

**Just a quick note**

I have tested single image based on `golang`, so when I call `docker-compose down` here what I get:

```
version: "3.1"
...
command: tail -f /dev/null   # stopping container takes about 10 sec.
tty: true                    # stopping container takes about 2 sec.
```

My system info:

```
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (64-bit)
Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c
docker-compose version 1.26.0, build d4451659
```

Answer (score 3):

As the commenter stated, we'd have to see the Dockerfile in question to give you a complete answer, but this is a very common mistake.  I can pretty much guarantee that the command you're trying to run is starting a background process.  This might be the command you'd run in non-Docker situations, but it's the wrong thing to do in a Dockerfile.  For instance, if what you're running is typically defined as a system service, you might use something like "systemctl start".  That would start the process in the background, which will not work.  You have to run the process in the foreground, so the entire process will block.

Answer (score 2):

Add entrypoint to docker-compose file

```
entrypoint: ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick `docker run` option, in a tiny busybox image, as a one-liner:

```bash
docker run --rm --name forever busybox sh -c 'trap : TERM INT; tail -f /dev/null & wait'
```

If you want to exec into that container:

```bash
docker exec -it forever sh
```

You can stop it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and it will stop gracefully and without delay.

If you prefer a `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
services:
  forever:
    image: busybox
    command: 'sh -c "trap : TERM INT; tail -f /dev/null & wait"'
```

Based on [this](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1926#issuecomment-422351028).

Answer (score 0):

I have used some of the solutions above which works for `ubuntu` or `nodejs` images.  However they don't work with the `bitnami/azure-cli` image.  Whatever specified in `command` becomes argument(s) for the `az` command of that image.  After a bit of struggling, this is how the `docker-compose.yml` file should be:

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  azure-cli:
    image: "bitnami/azure-cli:latest"
    container_name: az-container
    entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
```

As @highjump points out above, this `entrypoint` option overrides the internal `command` option, and keeps the container running.

Answer (score 0):

This was the only way I could get it to work without using something like `tail -f /dev/null`. I read many of the answers here saying that adding `init` to the compose file should be enough and confirmed the same in Docker's documentation but I could not get it to work with `init` alone.

```
# compose.yml
services:
  my-test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    tty: true
    init: true
```

```
# dockerfile
FROM node:20-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache  --update bash

CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

Answer (score -3):

Okay I found my mistake. In the Dockerfile for the image used for compose I specified that the base image should be ubuntu:latest, but I previously created an image called ubuntu by myself and that image did not work. So I did not use the original ubuntu image but rather a corrupt version of my own image also called ubuntu.