# Docker-compose stops the container after entrypoint is done

Tags: sql-server, bash, docker, docker-compose

I need sql server container with some database. I've prepared the following dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
ENV ACCEPT_EULA Y
ENV SA_PASSWORD yourStrong(!)Password
WORKDIR sqlserver
COPY load_db.sh load_db.sh
COPY /resources/sql/ sql
ENTRYPOINT ./load_db.sh
```

So it runs load_db.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SERVER_OUT=/var/log/sqlserver.out
TIMEOUT=90
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr &>${SERVER_OUT} &

function server_ready() {
    grep -q -F 'Recovery is complete.' ${SERVER_OUT}
}

echo 'Wait until Microsoft SQL Server is up'
for (( i=0; i<${TIMEOUT}; i++ )); do
    sleep 1
    if server_ready; then
        break
    fi
done
echo 'Microsoft SQL Server is up'

/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P ${SA_PASSWORD} -Q "CREATE DATABASE MarketDataService;"
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P ${SA_PASSWORD} -d MarketDataService -i sql/2018.0100.000000001.Add_Layout_table.sql
```

To run it I've prepared the followinf docker-compose file:

```
services:
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-db
    ports:
    - 1433:1433
```

When I try to run `docker-compose up --build` it looks okay.
I have output:

```
db_1       | Wait until Microsoft SQL Server is up
db_1       | Microsoft SQL Server is up
db_1       |
db_1       | (3 rows affected)
```

But after it is exited...

```
amptest_db_1 exited with code 0
```

To solve it I've tried to add `tty: true` but it doesn't make sense. The same output. How can I keep alive my container by docker-compose? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45450456/3561198) I've found `tail -F anything`. It works but looks terrible. Is there a better way?

**Upd:** I've stayed with `tail -F '/var/log/sqlserver.out'`

Comment: probably no. usually use constructions like that to avoid container stop.

Comment: It says `db_1       | tail: cannot open 'anything' for reading: No such file or directory`. At least how to avoid this message?

Comment: You sure there are no errors? What's in `docker logs containerid`?

Comment: means, any file exists in container. Try `/var/log/messages` for example.

Comment: A `container` stays up and running as long as its *main process* (set by `CMD`) is running. What `CMD` are you using?

Comment: @tgogos I don't use `CMD`. I use `ENTRYPOINT` and it runs just `load_db.sh`