# Dockerfile won´t run CMD properly or Ports are not exposed

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apache-nifi

I wan´t to play around with Dockerfiles a bit. So I tried running Apache Nifi in Docker. I know that there is already a container available, this is for training purpose.
I configured my Dockerfile as followed:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["sh","nifi-1.9.0/bin/nifi.sh","start"]
```

Now this seems to work, but when I try to run the container with:

```
docker build --tag nifid .
docker run --name nifi-app -p 8080:8080 nifid
```

It seems to run but the port is neither exposed, nor can I reach the App via localhost:8080.
Any suggestions on how to proceed?
This is what docker ps --all shows me

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS               NAMES
ccf75612d5ac        nifid               "sh nifi-1.9.0/bin/n…"   20 hours ago        Exited (0) 20 hours ago                       nifi-app
```

I realize that the app was excited now.
Anything wrong i the Dockerfile?

EDIT:
The docker logs [Container ID] spitted following:

```
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre
NiFi home: /app/nifi-1.9.0

Bootstrap Config File: /app/nifi-1.9.0/conf/bootstrap.conf
```

EDIT:
Found a nice "documentation" https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi/dockerfile

A bit to indepth but it should to the job

Comment: Looks like the container is down !! start the container. Please check [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-expose-port-on-running-container/3252/7)

Comment: Edit your post with the result of `docker logs nifi-app`

Comment: This would happen if the `nifi.sh start` command launched the server in the background and returned.  You need to launch it as a foreground process.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I added the Docker logs

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like your container has stoppen (status Exited)

```
docker ps (shows running containers)
docker ps -a (shows all containers, even stopped)
```

Try

```
docker logs <container-id>
```

To see the output from the container. It will properly tell you why the container stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Container need a pid 0 process to run forever until killed or errors.

For example, 
[image]

Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45450456/1926952 to keep a container running