# How to run a command without block terminal

Tags: docker-compose

I need only to "unblock" my terminal after `docker-compose up`... There are some option or setpup for it?

NOTES: my service is using `unless-stopped` so supposing that not need to use `-d` on the command line.

```
    ...
    image: etc/etc
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: host
    ...
```

---

PS: I need [keep container running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546755/docker-compose-keep-container-running) and I not need to use `&` in the terminal line, I need no extra-process running. Seens ["-t"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40026942/287948) ... The name of this "blocking mode" is "pseudo-TTY"?

Answer (score 2):

All examples say to use simplest `docker-compose up` but it is not, seems that you MUST use option even when yml say what you want: `sudo docker-compose up --detach`.