# Containers created with docker-compose exited

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Whenever I try `docker-compose up -d`, my container exits with code `0`.

I have following `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
    version: "3"
    services:
      ansible:
        container_name: controller
        image: centos_ansible
        build:
          context: centos_ansible
        networks:
          - net
    
    networks:
      net:
```

The Dockerfile inside `centos_ansible`:

```
    FROM centos
    RUN yum install python3 -y && \
    yum install epel-release -y && \
    yum install ansible -y
```

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45450456/4676641

Comment: Your Dockerfile doesn't actually specify a `CMD` to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not specify nothing to do to your container and, as a consequence, it exits immediately.

You have several ways to tell the container what to do. Please, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile) great SO question for further information.

As you are using docker compose, you can indicate the `command` the container must execute:

```
services:
  ansible:
    container_name: controller
    image: centos_ansible
    command: ansible-playbook playground.yml
    build:
      context: centos_ansible
    networks:
      - net

networks:
  net:
```

It seems you are trying to run `ansible` from docker. Please, see [this](https://medium.com/@iced_burn/run-ansible-with-docker-9eb27d75285b) article, perhaps it will give you some additional ideas for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your container running, you need to tell it to do something.

You can do this, as another answer mentioned, by adding an `ENTRYPOINT` to your Dockerfile. Alternatively, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45450456/4676641), you can add a command like this, or do something more useful:

```
version: "3"
services:
  ansible:
    container_name: controller
    image: centos_ansible
    build:
      context: centos_ansible
    networks:
      - net
    command: tail -f /dev/null

networks:
  net:
```

Or if you'll need get a shell into the container, you can add the `tty: true` option to your service.

Answer (score 0):

Your docker container only keeps running if there is something to run inside your container. Try adding an `ENTRYPOINT` to your Dockerfile! (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)