# Docker-compose up fails with exit code 135

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js

I'm trying to build a simple `next.js` app with Docker compose but it keeps failing on `docker-compose build` with an exit code 135. I'm running it on a Mac M1 Pro (if that is relevant).

I couldn't find any resources pointing to an exit code 135 though.

- This is the `docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  next-app:
    image: node:18-alpine    
    volumes:
      - ./:/site
    command: >
      sh -c "npm install && npm run build && yarn start -H 0.0.0.0 -p 80"
    working_dir: /site
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

And the logs:

```bash
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container next-app  Created                                                                                                       0.0s
Attaching to next-app
next-app  | 
next-app  | up to date, audited 551 packages in 3s
next-app  | 
next-app  | 114 packages are looking for funding
next-app  |   run `npm fund` for details
next-app  | 
next-app  | 5 moderate severity vulnerabilities
next-app  | 
next-app  | To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
next-app  |   npm audit fix --force
next-app  | 
next-app  | Run `npm audit` for details.
next-app  | 
next-app  | > marketing-site-v2@0.1.0 build
next-app  | > next build
next-app  | 
next-app  | info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
next-app  | 
next-app  | ./pages/cloud.tsx
next-app  | 130:6  Warning: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
next-app  | 133:6  Warning: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
next-app  | 150:6  Warning: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
next-app  | 
next-app  | ./pages/index.tsx
next-app  | 176:10  Warning: Image elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
next-app  | 
next-app  | ./components/main-content-display.tsx
next-app  | 129:6  Warning: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
next-app  | 
next-app  | info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
next-app  | info  - Creating an optimized production build...
next-app  | Bus error
next-app exited with code 135
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what's in your `package.json` file - I would try this.

Spin up your vanilla `node:18-alpine` image without installing dependencies via the adjusted compose file below.

```
version: '3'

services:
  next-app:
    image: node:18-alpine   
    container_name: my_test_container
    volumes:
      - ./:/site
    command: >
      sh -c "tail -f /dev/null"
    working_dir: /site
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

The command being used here

`sh -c "tail -f /dev/null"`

is [a popular vanilla option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546755/docker-compose-keep-container-running) for keeping a container up and running when using compose (and when not executing some other command e.g,. `npm start` that would keep the container running otherwise).

I have also added a `container_name` for reference here.

Next, enter the container and try running each command in your original `sh` sequentially (starting with `npm install`).  See if one of those commands is a problem.

You can enter the container (using the `container_name` above) via the command below to test

`docker container exec -u 0 -it my_test_container bash`

As an aside, at some point I would pull commands like `npm install` from your compose file back to a Dockerfile defining your image (here `node:18-alpine`) and any additional custom installs you need for your application (here contained in `package.json`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I troubleshooted the commands in the container and the error comes from `npm run build` but I still can't figure out what is causing it. I've updated my question with my `package.json` if that helps

Comment: I searched for it and apparently removing the `node_modules` and running `npm install` again solved.
I accepted your answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You did use sh commend in docker-compose which is not a good practice to use docker.
You need docker-compose.yml along with Dockerfile as mentioned below.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  next-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

**in Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16.15.1-alpine3.16 as site

WORKDIR /usr/src/site

COPY site/ .

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 80
CMD  npm start
```

after this changes you just need a single command to start server.

```
docker-compose up --build -d
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But when running the `docker-compose up` command, it's not able to find the `yarn start` See: 
`next-app-1  | /bin/sh: yarn start: not found`

Comment: you can use  npm start as well. check npm start in cli if it works fine you can use that one. i mentioned yarn due to you mentioned yarn in your question.